# adding html to the mat-optgroup label

Tags: angular, angular-material

Is it possible with Angular Material to give a HTML template for the label of an optgroup of an autocomplete component, instead of binding a string to the `label` input? The `label` property escapes any HTML tags.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've played a little bit, and it looks like **you can do that**, you just need to **remove** `[label]` input value and put your **custom template** inside of `<mat-optgroup>` like:

```
<mat-autocomplete #autoGroup="matAutocomplete">
        <mat-optgroup *ngFor="let group of stateGroupOptions | async">
          <!-- here i put my custom button instead of label --->
          <button mat-raised-button color="primary">{{group.letter}}</button>
          <mat-option *ngFor="let name of group.names" [value]="name">
            {{name}}
          </mat-option>
      </mat-optgroup>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

Example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-evacck?file=app/autocomplete-optgroup-example.html) (I put buttons instead of plain labels). Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the example, it shows that anything you put inside the <mat-optgroup> tag that isn't inside the <mat-option> is actually used as content for the label!